# What is a good asp.net (NOT MVC!) reference application for a beginner?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, reference

I'm looking for a good asp.net webforms reference application.

We have some developers with VB6 experience, but no web application experience.  I'd like to provide them with a couple of example apps that make use of a few simple forms, some user controls, db access, etc. An application that made use of a separate project for classes would be a nice bonus.

There seem to be a lot of very simple examples/tutorials for given features, but I can't find a good reference app that covers all of the above-mentioned topics.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Because we're stuck using webforms for the foreseeable future.  This is a maintenance position for a suite of intranet apps.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the ASP.NET starter kits [here](http://www.asp.net/community/projects/) on the asp.net site. They are pretty diverse. My suggestion would be to actually try the hosted versions until you find one that suits the features you're trying to demonstrate. BeerHouse is a great start.

Comment: Unfortunately, The BeerHouse is a) in C#, and b) uses MVC

Comment: Ah, well, that's a big change. The version I have downloaded on my hard drive is in both C# and VB.NET and states "TheBeerHouse starter kit enables you to implement a website with functionality typically associated with a CMS/e-commerce site. This website demonstrates key features of ASP.NET 2.0 and is the sample used in the book, "ASP.NET 2.0 Website Programming / Problem - Design - Solution." "

Comment: There's two links on the download page - 2.0 MVC and 1.0 WebForms - or did you see it and say that it's not a great start any more because it's out of date?

Comment: And under the 1.0 WebForms project there's an option to download it in VB.

Comment: I said it because @chris said it was a C# MVC project. I'll re-re-edit the post to reflect what I originally thought. Thanks Nate!

Comment: I didn't notice the other verison under Releases.  The 1.0 vb version looks like a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This one looks pretty interesting.  It's a shameless plug for the Infragistics controls, but it looks like they're doing some non-trivial things:

> The reference application shows the
>   use of web services, client side java
>   scripting, XML data binding and other
>   real world code samples.

http://devcenter.infragistics.com/RefApps/Expense/Expense.aspx

Comment: I looked at that one, too, awhile ago. Unfortunately, its more than just a plug for Infragistics, its actually based completely around their controls. It doesn't appear to have much value unless you are trying to learn their control suite.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/community/projects/

Starter kits are a good place to look...